# Novo operador no python 3.8.5

Tags: python-3.x, operadores

No python 3.8.5 foi adicionado o operador **:=**, gostaria de saber pra que ele serve

Comment: Nada como a documentação: "There is new syntax := that assigns values to variables as part of a larger expression.". Em https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html tem exemplo de utilização logo no primeiro item.